# SQL to resume suspended messages in order

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009, biztalk-deployment

We have an upcoming deploy for a system that processes a lot of messages through BizTalk. Since those messages are cumulative updates they need to be queued up during the deployment outage then processed in order when the deploy is finished. Since there may be a large number of them it’s difficult to do this manually.

One possible solution is to leave the send port stopped and let the messages suspend. We can then resume them in order when the deployment is completed.

Is it possible to run a SQL script (or a tool) against the BizTalk messagebox database that will resume suspended messages, for a specific port, in order of receipt?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an ordered requirement (you either do or don't), then the Send Port should be marked for **Ordered Delivery**.

If so, then when you Start a Stopped Send Port, the messages will be processed in the same order they were submitted.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I needed to know. The messages are normally processed as they are received so ordered delivery is not set. Since there will be a backlog generated during the installation the need to enforce ordering is new.

Answer (score 0):

If you stop the port (but leave it subscribed) and start it again afterwards it should resume the message itself, or if not it is simple enough to go into the Administration Console and batch resume them.

However if the response messages of the send port are subscribed too by running Orchestrations you will not be able to un-deploy the Orchestrations until they have all completed, so stopping the send port would not work in this scenario.

Sometimes one option is if the initiating port is a one way receive, is to stop the receive location and let everything complete.  You can then stop the application and redeploy and restart it and the send port will pick up all the waiting message to process.

If the above is not possible you may want to look at doing a [side by side deployment](http://Checklist:%20Updating%20an%20Application%20Using%20Side-by-Side%20Versioning) where you increment the version numbers of all the assemblies in the solution so you can have both versions deployed at the same time and you can then allow the old version to finish running but have the new version processing any new messages.

Comment: If you resume multiple suspended messages in what order does it process them? Multiple updates to a single item need to be processed in the order they happened.

Comment: Do you have Ordered Delivery enabled on the send port?  Then in the order they are put into the message box, in fact you will just see a single instance suspended with all of them queued up in it.   If you don't have it enabled then even when running normally there is no guarantee that they would be ordered.

Comment: It's not ordered delivery unfortunately. It might be an option to turn it on. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The better option is to send messages to msmq, usually there is no extra coding required for this. You can just route messages to msmq using MSMQ adapter and then after deployment receive them in order as MSMQ adapter allows to receive in order. Just make sure you do a small test in yr QA environment before doing it in production.

Comment: Interesting idea. I'll try it out and see if I can get it to work